# Update Database in Ruby on Rails version 7.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, web, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello community I am new to ruby on rails, I have a problem with updating the database, when I try to update a record, all records are updated

[this is my article_controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXu0K.png)
[this is my router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNwtT.png)

I was reviewing the documentation and I saw that I do it similarly, I have searched for information on the internet and I can't find a solution

I want to update only one record by passing the id

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do:

```
@article.update(article_params)
```

when you do `Article.update` you are in fact updating all

EDIT: I'd also recommend following the conventions, using `resources :articles` is preferred https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web